# How to use different user for a server in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I want to set the user for one of the roles to a different one in my Capistrano file. How do I do that? Right now the user is set to "sshadmin" for all the servers.

```
set :user, "sshadmin"

server "198.227.6.30", :app
server "192.9.1.17", :web 
server "192.9.31.9", :db #I want this to use the user "sshadmin2"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Capistrano v3 You can use this directive:

```
role :app, %w{sshadmin@198.227.6.30}
role :web, %w{sshadmin@192.9.1.17} 
role :db,  %w{sshadmin2@192.9.31.9}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/)

> Servers can be defined in a bunch of ways, the following shows defining two servers, one where we set the username, and another where we set the port. These host strings are parsed and expanded out in to the equivalent of the server line after the comment:

```
role :web, %w{hello@world.com example.com:1234}
# ...is the same as doing...
server 'world.com' roles: [:web], user: 'hello'
server 'example.com', roles: [:web], port: 1234
```

Applied to your case

```
role :db,  %w{sshadmin2@192.9.31.9}
```